# 0 Swap Used Although Swappiness is 60

Tags: gnome, ram, swap

I have the [Vitals](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/) GNOME Extension, and I also have my swappines  value (in `/etc/sysctl.conf`) at the default: 60. I clicked on the Vitals extension and I looked in the Memory section, and it says 0.00 B of swap is used!

[image: Vitals Extension showing memory image]

See? It has been using no swap. When I installed Ubuntu a while ago, I didn't tweak with partitions, which means that I am **not** using a swap partition, and it's on the normal disk and partition.

How to make it actually swap memory?

Ubuntu 20.04.4

RAM/Memory on hardware: 7.5 GiB (8 gigs of ram)

Comment: If it isn't using swap that's because it hasn't needed to use swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wise person (@ChanganAuto) once wrote...

"*If it isn't using swap that's because it hasn't needed to use swap.*"

Your own output agrees with that assessment: You're using only 3.01 of your 7.90 GB of RAM. You must use all your RAM before the kernel will begin swapping. Your swappiness doesn't really become important until swapping begins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although the part where you said "You must use all your RAM before the kernel will begin swapping" is clearly incorrect because my kernel started swapping 20MB when I got around 50% memory. I will accept this answer since it is technically correct.